# How to add the multiple column as a primary keys in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I have an existing table with millions of records and initially we have two columns as partitioning key and clustering key and now I want add two more columns in a table as a partitioning key.

How?

Answer (score 5):

If you make a change to the partition key you will need to create a new table and import the existing data. This is due to, in part, the fact that a partition key is not equal to a primary key in a relational database. The partition key is hashed by Cassandra and that hash is used to find partitions on disk. If you change the partition key you change the hash value and can no longer look up the partition!

```
CREATE TABLE KEYSPACE_NAME.AMAR_EXAMPLE (
    COLUMN_1 TYPE,
    COLUMN_2 TYPE,
    COLUMN_3 TYPE,
    ...
    COLUMN_N TYPE
    // Here we declare the partition key columns and clustering columns
    PRIMARY KEY ((COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, COLUMN_3, COLUMN_4), CLUSTERING_COLUMN)
    ) 
    //If you need to change the default clustering order declare that here
  WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (COLUMN_4 DESC);
```

You could export the data to CSV using `COPY` and then import the data to the new table via `COPY` or use the `SSTABLELOADER`. There is plenty of documentation and walkthroughs on how to use those tools. For example, [this Datastax blog post](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/using-the-cassandra-bulk-loader-updated) talks about the changes made to the updated `SSTABLELOADER`. If you create a new table and import the existing data you will create new partitions and new hashes. Cassandra will not let you simply add additional columns to the partition key after the table has been created.

Understanding your data and the Cassandra data modeling techniques will help mitigate the amount of work you may find yourself doing changing partition keys. Check out the self-paced courses provided by Datastax. [DS220: Data Modeling](https://academy.datastax.com/courses) could really help.